# How do i get php object from json?

Tags: google-api

this case Google api v3 calendar

```
$array = $client->getAccessToken();
```

dump $array

```
$array = { ["access_token"]=>"i81bIkE" ["token_type"]=>"Bearer" ["expires_in"]=>3600 ["refresh_token"]=>"G3LQL_cQ" ["created"]=> 1495019807 }
```

i want to get ["refresh_token"] value.

```
$refresh_token = $array -> refresh_token;
```

i try this code ,but error

```
$token_array = json_decode($array);
```

error message

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...
```

plese help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy, as this tell you, you can't use this with `array`.

did you use:

> echo  $array['refresh_token'];

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` is a PHP method with string param. You try to pass an `array`.

`refresh_token` is a `string`. You can do :

```
$refresh_token = $array['refresh_token'];
```

to get it.